# touchpad windows 10 not scrolling ASUS X555L

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling, asus-laptop

I was wondering if there is a specific fix I need to preform in order to get my touchpad to scroll again. I read some of the other replies on this topic and it seems like this is a common problem yet I have tried one or two of the suggested solutions and have had no success. My computer is a ASUS X555L. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried one or two of the suggested solutions and have had no success" Please edit your question to include exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were.  This will prevent people suggesting things you've already tried, and help clarify the scope of the problem to answers.

Comment: Have you installed the Windows 10 drivers for the device?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you installed the following driver:

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/SmartGesture/SmartGesture_WIN10_64_VER405.zip

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 has a problem with the touchpad of older devices. On my laptop (2008 model Fujitsu Siemens E8310 with Synaptics Touchpad), my touchpad also works only partly. I.e. it works everywhere, except in Metro-apps (start menu, settings, email, ...). There's no fix and I don't think any vendor is going to update the drivers (even though your laptop is not really that old, but it didn't ship with Windows 10 initially).

Comment: Windows 10 does not have a problem with touchpad on older devices, it only has a problem, if you are not using a driver for the device itself.  Which honestly is the case for any version of Windows or any OS or devices for that matter.

Comment: Well, then Windows 10 didn|t make a good transition, because it worked flawlessly in lower versions. I understand that it's probably an incompatibility, but I don't see that this much changed and it's a problem of how Windows 10 handles touchpad-notifications for scrolling.

Comment: Then why the heck Microsoft posting on everyone's desktop with annoying popup/notify to update their computer?